# How can I use a GELF appender with play 2.2.3?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, logback

I have a play-2.2.3 application. I would like to send the logs to graylog2 server using GELF-TCP. I have tried using the me.moocar GELF logback appender, but it seems that there are issues because it is compiled with some other version of the logback core jar.

Can I configure logback to send logs (via TCP or UDP) to a graylog2 instance hosted elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [logstash-gelf](https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf) a try. It supports TCP and UDP channels (UDP is non-blocking). logstash-gelf is compiled against logback-classic version 1.0.13.

Example config:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration>
    <contextName>test</contextName>
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <appender name="gelf" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender">
        <host>udp:localhost</host>
        <port>12201</port>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <facility>java-test</facility>
        <extractStackTrace>true</extractStackTrace>
        <filterStackTrace>true</filterStackTrace>
        <mdcProfiling>true</mdcProfiling>
        <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSS</timestampPattern>
        <maximumMessageSize>8192</maximumMessageSize>

        <!-- This are static fields -->
        <additionalFields>fieldName1=fieldValue1,fieldName2=fieldValue2</additionalFields>

        <!-- This are fields using MDC -->
        <mdcFields>mdcField1,mdcField2</mdcFields>
        <dynamicMdcFields>mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields</dynamicMdcFields>
        <includeFullMdc>true</includeFullMdc>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="gelf" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just yesterday I used the moocar gelf appender https://github.com/Moocar/logback-gelf which has pretty similar configuration to the one you've mentioned. It works fine now.